# Maximise your profit in this die game!

Tags: probability, puzzle

You pick a nonzero number ($n$) of dice. 
The dice are tossed simultaneously until one, and only one, is a six. On success there is a payout of $p$ dollars. Otherwise, for each toss of the dice, there is a cost of $c$ dollars. Choose $n$ to maximise your profit.

Myself, I assumed that a maximum of $k$ rounds were played, where $k= p \div c $ . Then, the expected probability of success is: 
$$1 - (\frac{5n} {6^n})^k$$

However, I found that this doesn’t quite work because the  probability of the game reaching the $k$th is itself variable.

I wrote a Python program to simulate the game here,

```
import random

payout = 300 
rcost = 100
# Adjust these as per requirement
nsim = 10000

def compute(ndie):
    profit = 0
    while True:
        c = [random.randint(1, 6) for _ in range(ndie)]
        if c.count(6) == 1:
            profit += payout
            break
        else:
            profit -= rcost
    return profit

x = int(input("Number of die? "))
s = 0

for i in range(nsim):
    l = compute(x)
    s += l

print("You win {} on average ".format(s/nsim))
```

Problem credits: Unihedron, [source](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/28372167#28372167).

Comment: Is community http://stackoverflow.com/ better for this question?

Comment: This looks like a mathematical problem for me, unless I am mistaken. The program is only if someone wants to run a simulation.

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't the maximum expected profit attained at either $n = 0$ if $p \leq 6c$ or $n = \infty$ if $p \geq 6c$?

Comment: @MarcPaul Nope, for p = 500, and c = 100, it peaks at about n = 5, with an average profit of 350 dollars.

Comment: @Henry Okay, I shall fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of success on a single throw is $\dfrac{n 5^{n-1}}{6^n}$ making the expected number of throws until success $\dfrac{6^n}{n 5^{n-1}}$ and the expected profit from a game played until success $p-\dfrac{c6^n}{n 5^{n-1}}$.

This will be maximised when $\dfrac{6^n}{n 5^{n-1}}$ is minimised, which for integer $n$ is when $n=5$ or $6$.

In those cases, the probability of success on a single throw is $(\frac56)^5$, the  expected number of throws until success $(\frac65)^5$ and the expected profit from a game played until success $p-c(\frac65)^5$.

The optimal number of dice does not depend on $p$ or $c$, providing $c \gt 0$.

Comment: How do you obtain the expression for success on a single throw? The way I see it, there are 6^n events out of which n are favourable.

Comment: @Rishav The $n-1$ dice which need to be unfavourable have $5^{n-1}$ possibilities for what they show.  Multiply this by your $n$ and divide by your $6^n$

Comment: Okay, I understood it. Very elegant solution, thank you.